# Pro AngularJS - Could you help explain part of this code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading a book called Pro AngularJS by Apress and I am just trying to ensure I understand all of the code and I am a bit baffled by the following code.

Below is a custom filter in the book, which accepts 2 arguments, the data array and a property name. In the book, the property name is the category key in the data, and is set up to remove duplicate categories in order to display a list of navigation links to each category without duplication.

```
angular.module("customFilters", [])
    .filter("unique", function () {
        return function (data, propertyName) {
            if (angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyName)) {
                var results = [];
                var keys = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var val = data[i][propertyName];
                    if (angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
                        keys[val] = true;
                        results.push(val);
                    }
                }
                return results;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
} });
```

What I don't understand is the keys part within the for loop. Keys is defined as an object literal?
Then, within the for loop, for each item in the data that us looped over, if the keys[val] is undefined (what does this mean)?
Then keys[val] is set to true (what does this do?).

I sort of understand the rest, if it is undefined, we push the result to the results array to return it.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Put simply, it's just a way to remember that we already have processed the value `val`, and do not which to return duplicates, if it comes along again in the loop.**

You have to put something in the `keys` object, like `keys[val] = true;`, so that `keys[val]` becomes defined in the next loop iteration.

If you don't put anything into `keys[val]`, `angular.isUndefined(keys[val])` in the next loop with same value `val` will evaluate to `true`, and then your result would be duplicated (which isn't unique)

### Explanation and answer to your questions

> if the keys[val] is undefined (what does this mean)?

Basically means the key `val` doesn't exist in the object `keys`,
e.g. an object `{'age': 45}` contains the key `age` but doesn't contain the key `weight`

> Then keys[val] is set to true (what does this do?)

This sets the key `val` of the object `keys` to `true`, so somewhere `keys` object looks like this `{<val>: true, <other key>: ...,}`

So after that step, the key `val` is defined for the object `keys`, therefore `angular.isUndefined(keys[val])` condition is false

> what is the purpose of keys[val] in the first place? Sorry, just not clear on what it is doing.

The code uses an object `keys = {}` which behaves like a key/value data structure (a dictionary, or a map, in other languages), the goal is to remember that we already have processed `val`

If you don't remember the values you have already processed (returned), then you will return duplicates, and therefore your `unique` filter will no longer return unique values, which is the purpose of the code here

Comment: Thanks bakkal, but what is the purpose of keys[val] in the first place? Sorry, just not clear on what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks bakkal, that makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Let us see the first line `return function(data, propertyName)`
here data is the array of objects to be filtered against `propertyName(category in this case)`.

Then we define `var keys = {}` i.e, an empty object.

Now through for loop we are putting the value of `propertyName(category in this case)` into variable `val`.

So for example the first object of data array is like this `[{ product: "product 1", category: 'Category 3'}, ....]`

Thus the value of `val = data[i][propertyName]` translates to `data[0][category]`, which evaluates to **Category 3**.

Now the line `angular.isUndefined(keys['Category 3'])` would evaluate to `true` for `if` condition (here we are asking if the given condition is undefined, which evaluates to true, thus if condition passes).

Within if loop we set the `keys[val] = true`, so that again this category name is not pushed to the results array.